# What is the correlation between Drop Off, Exits, and Bounces?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, bounce-rate, exit-pages

I am running through my analytics and noticed that my drop off in the behavior chart is always 100%. Which does not necessarily surprise me except neither bounce rate, or % Exits are 100%.

I understand bounce rate because if the session stays open, or they fill out the form then they are no longer a bounce. But shouldn't % Exit be 100% since they are leaving the page?

[image: Drop Off Behavior Chart]

Answer (score 2):

The three metrics are are all different.

**Bounces**: the number people that come to your website, view one page, and leave.

**Exits**: The number of people who exit from the site on that page. This metric counts sessions that start anywhere on the site.

**Drop offs**: A drop off occurs when someone exits the user flow that you are viewing. This does not necessarily mean that they are leaving the website.

For example if you set up a behavioral flow to track people who move from page `A -> B -> C`, and someone goes from page `A -> F` this will count as a drop off because it does not follow the flow that you have highlighted.

Thus, the behavioral flow in the photo is not implemented correctly. I would recommend reading up on flow reports [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2519986?hl=en), and [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2519989).

Answer (score -3):

This was driving me crazy tonight, I had the exact same problem.

You are looking in BEHAVIOR > Behavior Flow

But you need to be in AUDIENCE > Users Flow

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about why these reports are different and why the behavior flow report works the way it does?